# Stable equilibrium

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider the system:
$$ x'=(\epsilon x+2y)(z+1) $$
$$ y'=(-x+\epsilon y)(z+1) $$
$$ z'=-z^3 $$
where $\epsilon$ is a parameter. Find the parameters $\epsilon$ for which the system has a stable equilibrium at the origin.

---

I'm not sure about the definition of "stable equilibrium", and don't know how to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\cases{
x'=(\epsilon x+2y)(z+1) \\
y'=(-x+\epsilon y)(z+1) \\
z'=-z^3 
}\Rightarrow \cases{
x x'=(\epsilon x^2+2x y)(z+1) \\
2y y'=(-2xy+2\epsilon y^2)(z+1) \\
z'=-z^3 
}
$$

Adding the two first equations

$$
\cases{
\frac 12(x^2+2y^2)'-\epsilon(x^2+2y^2)(z+1)=0\\
\dot z+z^3=0
}
$$

and calling $u = x^2+2y^2$ we have

$$
\cases{
\frac 12 u'-\epsilon u(z+1)=0\\
z'+z^3=0
}
$$

here $z(t)\rightarrow 0$ and $u(t)\rightarrow 0$ as long as $\epsilon < 0$